# php mail() function changes characters and removes return breaks

Tags: php, email

this is what I have :

```
$msg = "1'2 ’3"4 “5”6 7~8!9@10#11$12%13^14&15*16(17)18}19{20"21:22?23>24<25 ";
mail("myemail@example.com","My subject",$msg);
```

when I receive the email I get this :

```
1&#039;2 ’3&quot;4 “5”6 7~8!9@10#11$12%13^14&amp;15*16(17)18}19{20&quot;21:22?23&gt;24&lt;25
```

so it changes the characters to html I guess? any ideas?
I need the email received to contain exactly what I had stored in $msg.thank you

it also removed return breaks I had. in the db the field has return breaks it is stored like this:

```
Hello $name

welcome to $websitename 

thank you, management
```

this is a lame example,but as you can see there are 2 empty lines. when the email is sent out those return breaks are ignored and its all in line any thoughts please

Comment: Have you tried setting the content type and encoding in the mail headers?

Comment: no I didnt set any encoding on the headers.

Comment: Sudhir's answer ought to work for you. The encoding was the first thing I thought about, since encoding troubles have been plaguing me in a couple projects over the last week or so. Good luck!

Comment: how about the return breaks? I made an edit to my issue.any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding headers, like:

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

See here: [PHP mail()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

Comment: any idea on the return break ?

Answer (score 2):

You have to encapsulate the message inside `base64` encoded format to prevent content mangling:

```
$msg = "1'2 ’3\"4 “5”6 7~8!9@10#11$12%13^14&15*16(17)18}19{20\"21:22?23>24<25";

$body = chunk_split(base64_encode($msg));

mail("myemail@example.com", "My subject", $body, "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64");
```

The way newlines are handled varies amongst different mail clients; for instance, Outlook is known to squash newlines but also offers a way to restore them.

For complete control you should go for HTML emails instead, optionally with text mode fallback.

Comment: any idea on the return break ?

Comment: @fogsy This depends on the mail client; Outlook is known to squash newlines (but it has an option to restore them). If you want complete control you should send HTML emails.

Comment: has nothing to do with the email client, I receive the email in gmail and the return breaks are gone

Comment: @fogsy weird, it worked for me ... are you using `"\r\n"` as line separators?